# R Shiny App, Error in $<-.data.frame: replacement has 1 row, data has 0

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to R and Shiny.  I am writing a R Shiny app that creates a data frame of time series data from a specifically formatted data file.  Once the data file is loaded the contents of the data file is shown in "file contents" tab. Once the station is chosen, the time series is plotted on the "Chloride Time Series" tab.  The script should allow manipulation of the data frame (so one could exclude or include as many points as needed in the analysis) by clicking on or brushing points in the plot.

Unfortunately, upon a click on the plot, the app crashes and I get this cryptic error:  **Warning: Error in $<-.data.frame: replacement has 1 row, data has 0
Stack trace (innermost first):
    68: $<-.data.frame
    67: $<-
    66: nearPoints
    65: observeEventHandler [C:\Users\bp\OneDrive\blah blah blah]
     1: runApp
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer**

The error is derived from code to exclude data that I, nearly verbatim, lifted from a working app.

The full code is below:

```
        #
#
#check for packages and install if not installed
packages <- c("shiny", "lubridate", "shinyFiles", "readtext","ggplot2", "reshape2", "dplyr")
if (length(setdiff(packages, rownames(installed.packages()))) > 0)
{
  install.packages(setdiff(packages, rownames(installed.packages())))  
}
#require packages above
require("lubridate")
require("shinyFiles")
require("readtext")
require("shiny") 
require("ggplot2")
require("reshape2")
require("dplyr")

# Define UI for application that reads the file and displays the details of the file that was uploaded
ui <- fluidPage(headerPanel("Seasonal Mann-Kendall Regression and Linear Regression Tests"),

                  sidebarLayout(
                                  sidebarPanel(
                                                fileInput("file", 
                                                          "Browse to file",
                                                          multiple=TRUE,
                                                          accept=c("text/csv","text/comma-serparated-values,text/plain",".csv", ".txt"),
                                                          placeholder ="No file selected"
                                                          ), #end shinyFilesButton
                                                          helpText("Max file size is 5 MB"), 

                                                #check box in case data is loaded with a header
                                                checkboxInput("header","Header",FALSE),


                                                selectInput("stations","Select Stations:  ",
                                                                      choices =  NULL,#doesn't know what the station names are yet.
                                                                      selected = NULL,
                                                                      multiple = FALSE,#to not select multiple stations
                                                                      selectize = TRUE #will bring up a list of stations to select
                                                            )#end selectInput  


                                              ),#end side bar panel

                                  #will display data in file when the file is read in
                                  mainPanel(
                                            tabsetPanel(id = "inTabset",
                                                        tabPanel(title = "File Contents", tableOutput("contents")),
                                                        tabPanel(title = "Chloride Time Series", 
                                                                 plotOutput("plot1", 
                                                                            click = "plot1_click",
                                                                              brush = brushOpts(
                                                                              id = "plot1_brush"
                                                                              )#end brushOpts
                                                                            ),#end plotouput
                                                                 actionButton("exclude_toggle", "Toggle Points"),
                                                                 actionButton("exclude_reset", "Reset")                                            

                                                                 )#end tab panel

                                                        )#end of tabsetpanel
                                            )#end main panel

                              )#end sidebarlayout

                )#end the fluidpage ui


server <- function(input, output, session) {



          output$contents <-renderTable({
      #Step 1: SELECT THE TEXT FILE
                                    inFile <-input$file

                                    if (is.null(inFile))
                                      return(NULL)

                                    read.table(inFile$datapath,
                                               header = input$header,
                                               sep="",
                                               quote="",
                                               dec = "."

                                              )#end read.table


                                        })#end of output$contents assignment

            #for the update select input invoke observe function
                        observe({

                          #define cupstat to be the first column of the file data, not the data frame

                          x<-input$file
                          if (is.null(x))
                            return(NULL)

                          #read in the table and store it in a variable named datTable
                          datTable<-read.table(x$datapath, 
                                                header = FALSE,
                                                sep = "",
                                                dec = "."
                                              )#end read.table

                              #get the station IDs             
                              cupStat<-unique(datTable[,1]
                                             )#end unique   



                               #update the select input called STATIONs  
                              updateSelectInput(session,"stations",
                              label = "Select Station",
                              selected = input$stations,#assign the value selected by the user to this select input, otherwise the app will revert back to NULL
                              choices = cupStat

                                               )#end updateselectinput


                              #UPDATE the CHLORIDE TIME SERIES PLOT OUTPUT TAB TITLED "CHLORIDE TIME SERIES" 
                                #STEP 2:  GET A DATA FRAME FROM datTable that corresponds to the station selected in 
                                #the selectInput station
                                stationData<-filter(datTable,datTable[,1]==input$stations)

                                #STEP3:  STRIP THE DATES AND THE CHLORIDE CONCENTRATIONS FROM THAT DATA FRAME TO MAKE A another data frame
                                xCl<-ymd(stationData[,3], locale = "English") #dates
                                yCl<-stationData[,4] #chloride concentration

                                chlorideTS<-data.frame(xCl,yCl)


                                ##############################################################################################
                                #for storing which rows from chlorideTS have been excluded


                                vals <- reactiveValues(
                                  keeprows = rep(TRUE, nrow(chlorideTS))
                                )

                                output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
                                  # Plot the kept and excluded points as two separate data sets
                                  keep    <- chlorideTS[ vals$keeprows, , drop = FALSE]
                                  exclude <- chlorideTS[!vals$keeprows, , drop = FALSE]

                                  ggplot(keep, aes(chlorideTS[,1], chlorideTS[,2])) + geom_point() +
                                    geom_smooth(method = lm, fullrange = TRUE, color = "black") +
                                    geom_point(data = exclude, shape = 21, fill = NA, color = "black", alpha = 0.25)

                                })
                                #***********************************Error Message likely derived from the code below**************************
                                # source for code below:  https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/plot-interaction-exclude.html

                                # Toggle points that are clicked
                                observeEvent(input$plot1_click, {
                                  res <- nearPoints(chlorideTS, input$plot1_click, allRows = TRUE)

                                  vals$keeprows <- xor(vals$keeprows, res$selected_)
                                })

                                # Toggle points that are brushed, when button is clicked
                                observeEvent(input$exclude_toggle, {
                                  res <- brushedPoints(chlorideTS, input$plot1_brush, allRows = TRUE)

                                  vals$keeprows <- xor(vals$keeprows, res$selected_)
                                })

                                # Reset all points
                                observeEvent(input$exclude_reset, {
                                  vals$keeprows <- rep(TRUE, nrow(chlorideTS))
                                })



                                })#end observe for updateSelectInput


                                }#end of server function


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I suspect that the error results from a reactive expression that is within an observe function, however, I have no evidence to suggest that this is the case.  Regardless, if anyone has suggestions with this code I would be happy to hear them.  Thank you.

Comment: Without the output from `traceback`, it's impossible to know when/where the error happens. The `$<-` assignment operator is tricky for data.frames: you can really only grow them "wide" except for length 1 objects or, more riskily, recycled vectors. If you need a complex data structure that grows wide and long at varied rates, use a `list` instead. Else, find a way to allocate what you need up-front and be done with it.

Comment: Hmm, you could try some debugging to steps to isolate the problem. You can run the app in showcase mode, which will highlight what code is being executed when you interact with your application. `shiny::runApp(display.mode="showcase")`

You can also add `browser()` statements or breakpoints where you think the code is breaking. More here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/debugging.html