# No output from Reactive Module using selectizeGroup with EventReactive

Tags: r, filter, shiny, reactive

I am creating a dashboard that queries a db to produce a table. The query's filter contains a reactive variable in which its value is determined by the slider. However, I cannot put filters on the resulting reactive dataset since shinyWidgets does not take in reactiveValues as input. I looked t similar posts, however none of them has a solution for a reactive dataset produced in an eventReactive function. Below is the code with fake data, not showing the real query or db connection but a preview of it (it is commented out). Note that the query must be located inside eventReactive or huge errors get thrown at me. Also, the date gets filtered during the query, but I want to use filters on the resulting data results for the other 2 variables AFTER the query runs. I've also tried to use callModule outside of eventReactive() by using data() as the argument but it does not take in reactive objects. It also does not like data tables so data frames must be used instead.

- I updated code based on conversation in comment section. I got everything besides res_mod() to work with ObserveEvent instead of eventReactive. When generating an actual query though I get an error:
  Warning: Error in $<-.data.frame: replacement has 0 rows, data has 2524782
  48: stop
  47: $<-.data.frame
  45: observe
  44: 
  1: runApp
  [R Shiny App, Error in $<-.data.frame: replacement has 1 row, data has 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48448889/r-shiny-app-error-in-data-frame-replacement-has-1-row-data-has-0) is a post that shows this error.

Also, the filters don't seem to work.

```
# Load Packages----
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(DBI)
library(odbc)
library(shinyWidgets)

# Global Options----
options(DT.options = list(pageLength = 25,searching = FALSE))
values <- reactiveValues(df_data = 
                      NULL)


# Initialize Variables
data_summary = data.table(Device_Status = c("Healthy_Devices","Unhealthy_Devices"),Total = c(0,0))

# Establish Snowflake Connection----
con1 <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 
                  .connection_string = "Driver=/opt/snowflake/snowflakeodbc/lib/universal/libSnowflake.dylib; 
                              Server=spireon.snowflakecomputing.com; 
                              authenticator = externalbrowser;
                              UID = sdaner@spireon.com;
                              Database = SPIREONDWBI_DEV;
                              role = DEV_SQL_DEV")
# UI----
ui <- fluidPage(
    
  
    sidebarPanel(
     
        # Slider
        sliderInput(inputId = "num", 
                    label = "Number of Previous Days from Today", 
                    value = 1, min = 1, max = 365),
        # Action Button
        actionButton(inputId = "click", label = "click to refresh"),
        # Space
        hr(),
        # Filters
            selectizeGroupUI(
                id = "my-filters",
                label = h3("Filters:"),
                inline = FALSE,
                params = list(
                    var_one = list(inputId = "var_one", title = "Select Account", placeholder = 'select'),
                    var_two = list(inputId = "var_two", title = "Select Device Type", placeholder = 'select')
                            )
                         )
               
            ),
    
    mainPanel(
        DT :: dataTableOutput("table"),
        plotOutput("barChart"))
)

# Server----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
 
  
observeEvent(input$click, {
    
    #Initialize Date
    past_date = Sys.Date() - input$num
    
    # Create Query
    query = paste("SELECT 
                      c.calendar_date,
                      c.device,
                      IFNULL(d.dailyautoloc,0) dailyautoloc,
                      d.account,
                      d.device_type
                      FROM SPIREONDWBI_DEV.DANER_TEST.CALENDAR_DEVICE_V2 c
                      LEFT JOIN SPIREONDWBI_DEV.DANER_TEST.DEVICEHEALTH d
                      ON c.calendar_date = d.date
                      AND c.device = d.device
                      WHERE c.calendar_date =","'",past_date,"'","
                      ORDER BY dailyautoloc DESC")
    
    values$df_data = as.data.frame(DBI::dbGetQuery(con1, query))
  

     
    })
  

  

# 
#   observe({
#   if(!is.null(values$df_data)){
# 
# 
#       res_mod = callModule(
#         module = shinyWidgets::pickerGroupServer,
#         id = "my-filters",
#         data = values$df_data,
#         vars = c("var_one","var_two")
#       )
# 
#   }
#    })





  

  
  # Render Data Table
  output$table <- DT :: renderDataTable({
   values$df_data
    #res_mod()
  })
  
  # #  Calculate Healthy and Unhealthy Devices----
  # dt = reactive(as.data.table(data()))
  # summary = reactive(data_summary[,Total := c(dt()[DAILYAUTOLOC >=1,.N],dt()[,.N] - dt()[DAILYAUTOLOC >=1,.N])])
  # #observe(print(data()[[1,1]]))
  # 
  # output$barChart = renderPlot({
  #   
  #   ggplot(summary(),aes_string(x = names(summary())[1], y = names(summary())[2], fill = names(summary())[1])) +
  #     geom_bar(stat = "identity", position=position_dodge())+ 
  #     geom_label(aes(label = formatC(summary()[,Total],format = "d",big.mark=","))) +
  #     ggtitle(paste("Device Health Status For",data()[[1,1]],sep =" ")) +
  #     theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
  #           panel.background = element_blank(),
  #           axis.title.x = element_blank(),
  #           axis.title.y = element_blank(),
  #           plot.title = element_text(face = "bold",hjust = 0.4),
  #           axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black",size = 10),
  #           legend.position = 'none')
  #   
  # })
}

# Run the application----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO!

There are several problems with your code.  The most important one is that you don't assign the value returned by `callModule` to an object.  Not that that would do you any good, since you call `callModule` inside an `eventReactive`.  That - like nesting any reactive definitions - is a recipe for disaster.

If I understand you correctly, it's not necessary to use an `eventReactive` to get what you want: "the query must be located inside eventReactive or huge errors get thrown at me" is a symptom, not the root cause.

Also, the `date` column in your test dataset is a character, so it's not easy to do date-based arithmetic on it.

Finally, you're trying to combine obtaining the data from your module with filtering it for display.  That may be possible, but in attempting to identify the other problems with your code, I separated the two operations to help with debugging.

I *believe* this MWE does what you want.  I've used the `lubridate` package to make date manipulation more straightforward.

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(DBI)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(lubridate)

# Establish Snowflake Connection----
# con1 <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 
#                   .connection_string = "")

# Create Data
a_df <- list()
a_df[['date']] = lubridate::as_date(c("2021-12-30",("2021-12-29"),("2021-12-28")))
a_df[['var_one']] = c('a','b','c')
a_df[["var_two"]] = c(1,2,3)
dt <- do.call(data.table::CJ, a_df)

# UI----
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    
    # Slider
    sliderInput(inputId = "num", 
                label = "Number of Previous Days from Today", 
                value = 1, min = 0, max = 3),
    # Action Button
    actionButton(inputId = "click", label = "click to refresh"),
    # Space
    hr(),
    # Filters
    selectizeGroupUI(
      id = "my-filters",
      label = h3("Filters:"),
      inline = FALSE,
      params = list(
        var_one = list(inputId = "var_one", title = "Select Account", placeholder = 'select'),
        var_two = list(inputId = "var_two", title = "Select Device Type", placeholder = 'select')
      )
    )
    
  ),
  mainPanel(
    DT :: dataTableOutput("table")
  )
)

# SERVER----
server <- function(input, output) {
rawData <-callModule(
        module = shinyWidgets::pickerGroupServer,
        id = "my-filters",
        #The below code would be used when running a query
        #data =  as.data.frame(DBI::dbGetQuery(con1, query)),
        data = dt, # Trying to mimic query results
        vars = c("var_one","var_two")
      )

filteredData <- reactive({
  rawData() %>% filter(date == (lubridate::today() - days(input$num)))
})
  
  # Render Data Table
  output$table <- DT :: renderDataTable({
    filteredData()
  })
  
}

# Run the application----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

**Update**
In response to OP's clarification...

I still maintain that `observeEvent` is the wrong way to go.  It returns an object of the wrong type.  Even if it is the way to go, placing the call to `callModule` within the call to `eventReactive` is incorrect because of scoping rules.

To make your filtered data depend only on the user's click on "Refresh" and not on any changes to the filter, you need to *add* a dependency on the action button and *remove* the dependency on the query.  You can do the former simply by referring to the action button and the latter by using the `isolate` function.  I've done this in my `filteredData` reactive rather than in the call to `renderDataTable` for `output$table` because this separates data wrangling from data presentation.  Here, that makes little difference, but in a more complex case where (say) several outputs depend on a single reactive, this makes for simpler, more robust code that is easier to maintain and debug.

The only change to my code above is in the `filteredData` reactive, which becomes:

```
filteredData <- reactive({
  input$click

  isolate({
    rawData() %>% filter(date == (lubridate::today() - days(input$num)))
  })
```

Comment: Thank you! I do need eventReactive because I don't want the query to hit the database until the user clicks "refresh". The date is an example of data I created. In the db, it is stored as a date variable. Is there a way to get this code working by using eventReactive() to filter out the date. The filters for var1 and var2 can be placed outside of eventReactive after the fact on that resulting dataset that the query generates.